# How to manage the creation of a c++ library

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I am developping a static library and I would like to be able to export the library and a part of the interfaces I use in it. Is there any tool to automate that process (other than writing a makefile by hand) ?

For exemple let's say I have a library coded in the following directory structure:

- mystuff/
  - main_entry_point_of_the_lib.h
  - some_code.cpp
  - innerfolder/
    - an_interesting_interface.h
    - some_code.cpp
  - innerfolder2/
    - an_uninteresting_interface.h
    - some_code.cpp

I would like to create the following structure:

- mystuff/
  - main_entry_point_of_the_lib.h
  - innerfolder/
    - an_interesting_interface.h
  - innerfolder2/
    - an_uninteresting_interface.h

Comment: Autotools can do this for you, it has distribution and install functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) for this. It's easy to use but really powerful. See [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html) for documentation.

**Some Pros:**

- Very powerful / configurable
- easy to use
- simple to add a cmake library to other (cmake) projects
- Commandline and GUI available
- Available on all major platform
- supports native- and cross compiling
- can generate project files for various IDE's incl. Makefiles

Some more documentation:

- [CMake Tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)
- [CMake by Example](http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/)